# while trying to clone GIT to my windows 10 pc it got an error

Tags: git

```
git clone XXX
Cloning into 'XXX'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 164, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (164/164), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (119/119), done.
remote: Total 164 (delta 29), reused 93 (delta 11)
Receiving objects: 100% (164/164), 584.65 KiB | 55.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (29/29), done.
fatal: cannot create directory at 'Day - 1 /Task1.1': No such file or directory
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry the checkout with 'git checkout -f HEAD'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "cannot create directory" when checkout a git remote branch windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828718/why-do-i-get-cannot-create-directory-when-checkout-a-git-remote-branch-windows)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+error+directory+name+space

Comment: Spaces at the end are automatically removed on Windows. Therefore the directory was automatically changed from `"Day - 1 "` to `"Day - 1"`.

Comment: thanks it work @robert

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is your directory name.

" Day - 1 "

There are two spaces in here. I think it cannot possible

Comment: it is working in linux but in windows 10 it is showing error

Comment: I think problem is the directory name because linux ext4 can have directory like that. But windows File systems cannot take that .